# How can I make a gradient flow in multiple directions?

Tags: css, svg, gradient, linear-gradients

I'd like to create an ambilight effect by using gradients.

In css3 you can let a gradient move from `top to bottom`, `bottom to top`, `left to right` or from `right to left` and you can use multiple colors. but only for one direction.

I want to combine 4 areas of an image, by calculating an average or dominant color for each area and then create a background for the image by using gradients.

[image]

I thought about using multible gradients but it would not look good when you create an gradient **ac** and another one **bd** and just place both behind the picture. (I marked the critical area.).

Do you have any Idea how this could be done?

**EDIT**: I don't want to mix the colors between the gradients, like in the picture. I'm satisfied with a smooth float between all colors.

**EDIT2:** I uploaded a demo of my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/HJtnG/

**Edit3:** we've learned this can't be accomplished with CSS3 but maybe with SVG. After some reaearching I've found this picture:

[image]

So I'll go with a colored circle like the one on the picture.

Comment: have you tried using radial gradients? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Comment: This is the same thing. you can only change colors from center to borders. You can't change the colors by the angle, which would solve my problem btw...

Comment: This is a nice idea, but i don't think it can be done with CSS. I would either use an image, or draw the gradient to canvas and have the canvas render it.

Comment: drawing it to a canvas would be okay, do you know any js code that does this?

Comment: For that kind of complex gradients, I'd go with an image. Am interested whether or not this would get an answer though. You have my +1, and I'll keep track of it :P

Comment: I have to process 10 fps so I can't create new images all the time. maybe I'll limit the gradients to 4 sides

Comment: You might consider svg. It's been a long time since I've done vector graphics, but you can find a simple formula for drawing radians to complete a 360 degree rendering. Where each radian could start with one color for the center point and another at the ending point, to form a sort of blending. Only caveat is you would need extremely high resolution to generate the original and save it to a bitmap.

Comment: so far I couldn't find anything for 360 degree rendering. Looks like it provides the same functions as the css gradient. (http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/)

Comment: nocturns2: The hint about the svg was correct. I managed to get a...similar result using svg. I don't know if it can be used for realtime processing, but it is the only way to get this done.

Comment: nocturns2 please submit your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 2020, you have more possibilities to achieve what you want considering new gradients and mask.

using `conic-gradient()`

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:conic-gradient(from 45deg,red,blue,green,yellow,red);
}
```

[image]

Using `linear-gradient` and `mask`:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,blue);
}
html::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,green,gold);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,transparent);
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff,transparent);
}
```

[image: Multi-color CSS linear gradient]

Using `radial-gradient` with `mask`

```css
html {
  background:radial-gradient(120% 120%,red 30%,#000);
}
html:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:radial-gradient(120% 120%,blue 30%,#000);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(transparent,#fff);
          mask:linear-gradient(transparent,#fff);
}
.full {
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  background:radial-gradient(120% 120%,green 30%,#000);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to right, transparent,#fff);
          mask:linear-gradient(to right, transparent,#fff);
}
.full:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:radial-gradient(120% 120%,gold 30%,#000);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(transparent,#fff);
          mask:linear-gradient(transparent,#fff);
}
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="full"></div>
```

[image: CSS radial-gradient with mask]

Comment: Nice answer! I'll look into it later :)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I do not understand the question, but I believe what you want is a rectangular gradient. And unfortunately SVG does not support this. The closest you could get would be to have multiple linear gradients with some alpha fading out while behind that is another linear gradient fading in.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) its free and you can do a lot of stuff with it. hope this can help.

Comment: They provide a gradient generator but it's not really related to this question. ;) Also nocturns2 has already given the correct answer